# Bloom filter optimization on an interval of inputs

Tags: algorithms, hash-function

I'v been tackling a problem with bloom filters.
I have a basic version working on paper, but I need to be able to put a large interval of numbers into the filter at a given time.

Let `I` be an interval within `[0,U]`.
The problem is to put `I` into set `S`, as well as query if `I` is within set `S` using an optimized bloom filter.

For inserting one element `l` into `S`, I hash it using k unique hash functions and set `B[h(l)] = 1` for each hash function.

To query if element `l` is within `S`, I must check for all hash functions 1 to k if `B[h(l)] = 1`. If so, I can claim `l` is within `S` with some probability.

For an interval of elements, I assume there is a faster way to store each element in interval `I` into set `S`, but I'm not sure how to get started other than iterating and hashing each element one by one for each hash function. I also have to check membership. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your other one?

Comment: This one had 4 views. When I posted my second one, this one shot up to 15 views. I assume my wording of this question was poorly done since no one answered so I tried to redo it. Sorry, new to stack exchange.